# Eclipse MAT showing momoryleak in ths code,Whats wrong with this code?

Tags: android

public class ProductListGetSet
{

```
static ArrayList<ProductListItems> productListItems;
ProductListItems items;

ProductListGetSet()
{

    productListItems = new ArrayList<ProductListItems>();

}

public static int getProductListCount() {

    return productListItems.size();
}

public void setProductListItems(String name, String price, String rating, String review) {

    items = new ProductListItems();
    items.productName = name;

    items.productPrice = price;
    items.productRating = rating;
    items.productReview = review;

    productListItems.add(items);

}

public static ArrayList<ProductListItems> getProductListItems() {

    return productListItems;

}

public void setProductListItemsWithoutReview(String name, String price, String rating) {

    setProductListItems(name, price, rating, "0");

}

public void setProductListItemsWithoutRating(String name, String price, String review) {

    setProductListItems(name, price, "0", review);

}

public void setProductListItemsWithoutRatingReview(String name, String price ) {

    setProductListItems(name, price, "0", "0");

}

public static void removeProductList()
{
    productListItems.clear();
}
```

}

I am getting records from database and saving to this class.At a time i will save more than 500 records.

Is there any solution or alternative for this?
I am getting out of memmory error()(Bitmap size exceeds VM budget).
Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static variable productListItems is being constructed in the constructor of `ProductListGetSet`. So if I construct an instance of `ProductListGetSet` and add 500 products using `setProductListItems()`, and in another point in my code, construct another `ProductListGetSet`, my code'll create another `productListItems` object. So the first 500 members of the original `productListItems` is in memory, and I am creating another copy of the variable.

If you are constructing many instance of `ProductListGetSet` in your code, say, in a loop, before the VM comes to your rescue, you might run out of memory.

Though I feel that there is something else that is doing greater damage, which is probably not in the code that you posted here.

Comment: thanks!!,yeah i am downloading images(around 500 at a time) from server and showing in a gridview.In this activity memory is 21299(MemoryInfo info = new MemoryInfo();  info.getTotalPss()).But when I am coming back it is releasing

Comment: Initially my App allocating 2.757 MB of heap [Heop size is 5.383 MB] and while crashing the status is Heap size is 6.195 MB and Allocated is 3.37MB.